# Using border-radius.htc does not result in rounded corners for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

I am trying to use the border-radius.htc solution to get rounded corners to display in IE8, but am having difficulty. In the HTML file, I am using an IE8 conditional placed near the top of the page that calls an IE8 specific stylesheet. In that stylesheet, I have the following rule:

```
.navbar .nav .active > a,
.navbar .nav .active > a:hover {
behavior: url("border-radius.htc");
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
border-radius:  5px 5px 0px 0px;
position:  relative;
zoom:  1;
```

}

When I go to view the page in IE8, the corners are still squared. Can anyone tell me why the rounded corners are not being applied in IE8? Is there something wrong with my CSS?

Comment: Use CSS3Pie instead of border-radius.htc -- it's newer and better. But frankly, if all else fails, maybe just let IE users go without rounded corners; it's not like it'll make any real difference to them. It might even encourage them to upgrade to a better browser.

Answer (score 1):

instead of border-radius use PIE.htc, download it from http://css3pie.com/ and put it in your file, the code is right, only replace behavior: url("border-radius.htc") with     behavior: url("PIE.htc").